# Login from textfile in python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to create a user login in python. Creating an account works but when trying to be an existing user it doesn't work.
This is the code for that section:

```
elif login == "existing":
        un = input("Username: ")
        pw = input("Password: ") 
        f = file = open(un + ".txt", "r")
        if(file.readline())== ('Username: ' + un):
            print("Welcome")
        elif(file.readline())!= ("Password: ",pw): 
            print("Incorrect username or password.")
            un = input("Username:") 
            pw = input("Password:") 
            text_file = open(un + ".txt", "r")
            un = input("Username:") 
            pw = input("Password:")
            f = file = open(un +".txt", "r")
            print('Incorrect, closing the program.')
            Menuv2.close()
        else:
            print('Invalid input.')
            'Menuv2.py'.close()
```

It doesn't print welcome even when the username and password is correct. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try to print both parts of the if to see what is different? You're using a lot of unnecessary parens btw, this should work: `file.readline() == 'Username: ' + un`

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to reside on the following line in your code:

```
if(file.readline())== ('Username: ' + un):
```

The `if` condition is checking if the username entered is equal to `"Username: inputted_user_name"`. The `input()` function on the following line:

```
un = input("Username: ")
```

doesn't append the entered username to `"Username: "`. That is only there to inform the user what he/she is entering so you should change your `if` condition to this:

```
if file.readline() == un:
```

Comment: The reason why it's equal to "Username: inputted_user_name" is because that's what is in the textfile.

Answer (score 0):

The logic is a bit flawed here as if the username is correct the password would never be checked. However the direct error is that `readline()` will contain a newline. You can use `file.readline().strip()` to remove it.

From [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects):

> f.readline() reads a single line from the file; a newline character (\n) is left at the end of the string, and is only omitted on the last line of the file if the file doesn’t end in a newline.

Additionally, since the format of the file is unknown in the question it is a difficult to tell if you should compare with `"Username: ..."` or just the entered data. Currently the content of the file must be:

```
Username: myusername
Password: mypassword
```

If that is not intended you need to change your comparison to:

```
if file.readline().strip() == un:
```